# Are Ink Cartridges Manufactured In USA Compatible With Printer Purchased Outside Of USA?

Tags: compatibility, inkjet-printer, ink

I have Brother MFC-240C machine. I want to order compatible ink cartridges and Brother original ink cartridges, but don't know if they will work in my machine.

I once ordered ink cartridges from UK and they worked.

Comment: Well if it's the original replacement and the same model no, why shouldn't they work?

Comment: @Sathya Wow, that's nasty..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best results, purchase the appropriate cartridge from Brother or an authorized reseller. These resellers can be located anywhere in the world but they all get the ink from Brother and should all be labeled appropriately.

What you want to avoid is Generic or Non-Standard ink cartridges made by a 3rd party. This includes refurbished cartridges. The quality control on these items are generally poor and even though they are labeled that they are compatible with the printer, they ofter don't actually work. That of course doesn't mean that you won't get a good cheap cartridge, but it's highly unlikely.

If you go the the [Brother Website](http://www.brother-usa.com/mfc/modeldetail.aspx?PRODUCTID=MFC240C&tab=supp) for this printer and click the "Buy online" button, it will list all of the authorized resellers. Get it from one of these retailers and you won't have any problems.

Hope this helps